# How to calculate intersections fo ellipse and line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I encounter a pythonic issue, which is copied from Appendix A of paper: [https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1878.\](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1878.%5C)
The code in this paper is really disturbing.
what does the line

```
sols=sorted([(v.real / v[2].real,np.dot(line,v.real)**2+
np.dot(v.real,ellipse).dot(v.real)**2 for v in V.T],
key=lambda aa:aa[1])[:2]
```

do? Besides, when I run the code it would encounter error and impies v[2].real is zero. Does the function defined below work?

```
def intersections_ellipse_line(ellipse,line, zero=1e-12):
    '''points of intersection between ellipse and line'''
    _,V=np.linalg.eig(np.cross(line,ellipse).T)
    sols=sorted([(v.real / v[2].real,
                  np.dot(line,v.real)**2+
                  np.dot(v.real,ellipse).dot(v.real)**2)
                for v in V.T], 
                 key=lambda aa:aa[1])[:2]
    return [s for s ,k in sols if k < zero]
```

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation of `numpy.real`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/generated/numpy.real.html)

Comment: I guess you should know about complex numbers, if you deal with quantum mechanics?

Comment: yeah. I know complux number.  The `v` looks like a vector in that code. Does v.real return the real part of each element of the vector?@Stefan

Answer (score 0):

There exists different types of numbers regarding natural numbers, floating-point numbers, integers etc. In addition to that, python supports complex type numbers (such as 3i + 5) which can not be expressed in a normal cartesian system, however, requires axes of real and imaginary. In your case, v.real returns the real parts of the complex numbers. Since you are calculating eigenvalues, there can exist complex solutions.